Why is my text spilling into the next column?
I've tried looking the the answer to this question, however every method I have used did not work. I have 4 columns I need in my website and when I put a huge (or relatively normal) sized paragraph into my HTML, my CSS spills the text into the next column, and weirdly cuts off at the end of the column its supposed to be in when the grid fully extends to the bottom of the page.
This is what I currently have going on, and I expected the text to be in one column going down, not to the next. This is my current CSS (I'm using CSS grid by the way):


.columns {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  column-count: 4;
  grid-column: 6;
  grid-row: 6 / span 8;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.col {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
<div class="columns">
  <div class="col"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x80/000/fff" id="image1">
    <p class="text">Ut efficitur dapibus lorem, a facilisis eros aliquet vel. Aliquam auctor sc, a facilisis eros aliquet vel. Aliquam auctor sc, Aliquam auctor sc, a facilisis eros aliquet vel. Aliquam auctor sc, Aliquam auctor sc, a facilisis eros aliquet vel. Aliquam
      auctor sc, Aliquam auctor sc, a facilisis eros aliquet vel. Aliquam auctor sc, Aliquam auctor sc, a facilisis eros aliquet vel. Aliquam auctor sc, Aliquam auctor sc, a facilisis eros aliquet vel. Aliquam auctor sc, Aliquam auctor sc, a facilisis
      eros aliquet vel. Aliquam auctor sc, Aliquam auctor sc, a facilisis eros aliquet vel. Aliquam auctor sc, Aliquam auctor sc, a facilisis eros aliquet vel. Aliquam auctor sc, Aliquam auctor sc, a facilisis eros aliquet vel. Aliquam auctor sc, Aliquam
      auctor sc</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x80/000/fff" id="image1">
    <p>Hi</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x80/000/fff" id="image1">
    <p>Hi</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x80/000/fff" id="image1">
    <p>Hi</p>
  </div>

</div>



Apologies if its so messy, I'm new at Web Dev. I appreciate any help!

Use grid to layout columns, instead of num-columns


.columns {
  width:auto;

  /* EDIT Using grid to lay this out */
  /* display: inline-block; */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);

  /* EDIT Set the number of columns with grid */
  /* column-count: 4; */

  grid-column: 6;
  grid-row: 6 / span 8;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.col {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;

  /* EDIT Debug */
  border: 2px solid brown;
}
<div class="columns">
  <div class="col">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x80/000/fff" id="image1">
    <p class="text">Col 1. Ut efficitur dapibus lorem, a facilisis eros aliquet vel. Aliquam auctor sc, a facilisis eros aliquet vel. Aliquam auctor sc, Aliquam auctor sc, a facilisis eros aliquet vel. Aliquam auctor sc, Aliquam auctor sc, a facilisis eros aliquet vel. Aliquam auctor sc, Aliquam auctor sc, a facilisis eros aliquet vel. Aliquam auctor sc, Aliquam auctor sc, a facilisis eros aliquet vel. Aliquam auctor sc, Aliquam auctor sc, a facilisis eros aliquet vel. Aliquam auctor sc, Aliquam auctor sc, a facilisis eros aliquet vel. Aliquam auctor sc, Aliquam auctor sc, a facilisis eros aliquet vel. Aliquam auctor sc, Aliquam auctor sc, a facilisis eros aliquet vel. Aliquam auctor sc, Aliquam auctor sc, a facilisis eros aliquet vel. Aliquam auctor sc, Aliquam auctor sc
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="col"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x80/000/fff" id="image1"><p>Hi. Col 2</p></div>
  <div class="col"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x80/000/fff" id="image1"><p>Hi. Col 3</p></div>
  <div class="col"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x80/000/fff" id="image1"><p>Hi. Col 4</p></div>
</div>



